# knockout binding on dynamically generated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using Knockout.js and i am pretty new in this. I created a [Example to my problem.](http://jsbin.com/umusog/3/edit) Here i am trying to bind the knockout binding to dynamically generated elements. But the binding are not applied properly to dynamically generated elements.

I am trying to synchronize the input text field with label element. So whatever we enter in the input field the same text will reflect in its corresponding label element. Please forgive me if i am not clear with my question and please ask me for clearance. Help me guys ? thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code you are not using one of the main feature of `knockout` - auto-generating html. Instead of using `jQuery` to add new row - use knockout `foreach` binding with `observableArray`. When you add new item to array knockout will automatically generate html markup.

Javascript:

```
function CourseViewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.textValue = ko.observable('');
}

function CeremonyViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.cources = ko.observableArray([new CourseViewModel()]);

    self.addCourse = function(){
        self.cources.push(new CourseViewModel());
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new CeremonyViewModel());
```

Html:

```
 <div id="menutab">
    <form id="createMForm">
        <input type="button" id="createmenu" value="Add menu" data-bind="click: addCourse"/>
        <div class="menu">
            <table data-bind="foreach: cources" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content" >
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="CourseName">CourseName</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"  data-bind="value: textValue, valueUpdate:'keyup'" class="CreateCourseName" name="CourseName" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="courseoptiontab">
    <form id="createCOForm">
        <div class="options">
            <table data-bind="foreach: cources" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label class="colabel">Course Name
                            <span class="forcourse" data-bind="text: textValue"></span>
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
          </table>
       </div>
    </form>
<div>
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/g5vxr/